# Plot X Y coordinates in PowerBI

Tags: r, python-3.x, powerbi, data-science

I've been provided with a PoweBI license and I have a set of x and y coordinates. I would like to plot each coordinate over a rectangle which represents a football pitch. At a later stage overlay an actual football pitch (see images below).

I would just like to get information/guidance on what I need to achieve it. I would then search for information on how to get to it. I need a starting point.

Do I need python or R skills to achieve it?

[image]

[image: field view]

[Heat Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYw65.png)

Thanks

Comment: I would call this a scatter plot. In `R` this could be created several ways, the most basic is `plot(dataframe$xPos, dataframe$yPos)`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will take it from you suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Scatter chart** visual in Power BI.

You either have to set the aggregation for xPos and yPos to "Don't summarize" (like I did here) or you have to put time[ISO-UTC] into the Values field.

Play around with the scaling and the layer order.

[image]

Comment: I had initially tried the scattered plot however I was not able to load the ypositions. Now I need to find the right background image which fits accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand your reply, as I did agree with your response. I was able to plot the data points over and image, however there is some offset. I need to find some good books and training on PowerBI.